# delete all the data that start with the same key from the database "quick.db"

Tags: discord.js, quick.db

Hello guys i'm trying to delete all the data that start with  `modapp_${message.guild.id}`

i try to use :

```js
let money = db.all().filter(a => a.ID.startsWith(`modapp_${message.guild.id}`))
db.delete(money)
```

but it's give me this error
`SQLite3 can only bind numbers, strings, bigints, buffers, and null`

can anyone help me pls

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you look at the [Quick.db Documentation](https://quickdb.js.org/overview/docs#delete) You will see that `.delete()` accepts a key but `.all()` gives you an array of values, they do not mention the return type, after looking at the [source code](https://github.com/lorencerri/quick.db/blob/master/src/methods/all.js#L9) it turns out that you get objects with ID and data as properties, you can map the id's and call delete for each one of them

```js
let money = db.all()
  .map(entry => entry.ID)
  .filter(id => id.startsWith(`modapp_${message.guild.id}`))

money.forEach(db.delete)
```

Alternatively you could use [Array#reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) to only loop once, mentioning this as an alternative since you would otherwise be looping 3 times

```js
let money = db.all().reduce((acc, val) => {
  if (val.ID.startsWith(`modapp_${message.guild.id}`)) {
    acc.push(val.ID)
  }

  return acc
}, [])
```